# Approval requirements with respect to Sign In With Apple

Tags: appstore-approval

Apple's requirement for an App must have Sign In With apple is not clear.

Basically there are three possibilities here:

1. An App implements their own Sign In only (no social or third party)
2. An App Implements social/third party only (nothing on their own)
3. A mix of #1 and #2

What Apple says is that "Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (...) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option"

The above to my basic understanding only refers to those Apps which use the mode #2. An app like ours come under the category of #3. However under section of exclusions in their guidelines it doesn't clearly state #3 Mode apps should not require Sign In With Apple.

Is it that Apple did not word this correctly but allows our apps of case # or I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: What Apple wrote also includes your app's case as well since your app also allows it's users to login with third party applications. If your app only had a login feature of your own then you would not need to add Sign in with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

For the clarification of your point...

> 1. An App implements their own Sign In only (no social or third party)
>
>    **Sign in with Apple is NOT REQUIRED**

> 2. An App Implements social/third party only (nothing on their own)
>
>    **Sign in with Apple is REQUIRED**

> 3. A mix of #1 and #2
>
>    **Sign in with Apple is REQUIRED**

In simple words...

- If your app is using **third-part login services like Facebook, Google, Linked In, Twitter, etc.**, then **You have to implement Apple ID Login** feature in your app.
- If your **app is not using login with third party service** then you **do not need to implement Apple ID login** in to your app.

For more details you can refer [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple).